# Parse and Play a .pls file in Android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-mediaplayer

can anybody help me how to parse and play this .pls file in android

```
 [playlist]
 NumberOfEntries=1
 File1=http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/
```

Answer (score 13):

A quick search resulted in this very basic [`PlsParser`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/App/github/org_npr_android_utilPlsParser_java.htm) from the NPR app that, by the looks of it, will simply parse the .pls file and return all embedded URLs in a list of strings. You'll probably want to take a look at that as a starting point.

After that, you should be able to feed the URL to a `MediaPlayer` object, although I'm not completely sure about what formats/protocols are supported, or what limitations might apply in the case of streaming. The sequence of media player calls will look somewhat like this.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource("http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/");
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.prepare(); //also consider mp.prepareAsync().
mp.start();
```

Update: As far as I can tell, you can almost literally take the referenced code and put it your own use. Note that the code below is by no means complete or tested.

```
public class PlsParser {
        private final BufferedReader reader;

        public PlsParser(String url) {
            URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        }

        public List<String> getUrls() {
            LinkedList<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    String url = parseLine(line);
                    if (url != null && !url.equals("")) {
                        urls.add(url);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return urls;
        }

        private String parseLine(String line) {
            if (line == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String trimmed = line.trim();
            if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
                return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
            }
            return "";
        }
}
```

Once you have that, you can simply create a new `PlsParser` with the url of the .pls file and call `getUrls` afterwards. Each list item will be a url as found in the .pls file. In your case that'll just be `http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/`. As said, you can then feed this to the MediaPlayer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what part you're having trouble with? I added some code related to the actual parsing to help you get started. If that's not what you're looking for, please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish.